# Boost Tokenizer strange symbols at start

Tags: c++, boost

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main() {
  std::string a("http://website/some-path/,file1,file2");
  char *ptr = (char *)a.c_str();
  boost::char_separator<char> delim(",");
  std::vector<std::string> pths{};
  boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(
            std::string(ptr), delim);
  std::optional<std::string> pref = std::nullopt;
  for (const auto& tok : tokens) {
    if (!pref) {
      pref = tok;
      std::cerr << "prfix is set: " << tok << std::endl;
      continue;
    }
    pths.push_back(*pref + tok);
  }
  for(auto &t : pths) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
 }
}
```

My output:

```
prfix is set: �site/some-path/
�site/some-path/file1
�site/some-path/file2
```

The question is, what is wrong with the above? If I work with `std::regex`, it is fine.

EDIT: the scenario with `*ptr` is the one I actually had: the original string was passed to a function as `char *`, hence the above. This is to answer the comment by @273K.

Comment: `std::string(ptr)` is a temporary string.  Don't use `tokens` after that string it refers to is destroyed.

Comment: What is purpose of `ptr` and the immediate `std::string(ptr)` if you have `std::string a`?

Comment: @Eljay That was it. Once I had a proper variable instead of the temporary one, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A lot can be simplified, at once removing the problems:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0ba14a5366cb725)**

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>

auto generate(std::string const& a) {
    boost::tokenizer tokens(a, boost::char_separator<char>{","});

    std::optional<std::string> prefix;
    std::vector<std::string>   result;
    for (const auto& tok : tokens) {
        if (!prefix)
            prefix = tok;
        else
            result.push_back(*prefix + tok);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    for (auto& t : generate("http://website/some-path/,file1,file2"))
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
http://website/some-path/file1
http://website/some-path/file2
```